# What are the possible values for a valid pointer?

Tags: c

Does the standard restrict possible memory addresses (which I would interpret as possible values for a pointer)? Can your code rely on some values to be never used and still be fully portable?

I just saw this in our code base (it's a C library), and I was wondering if it would be always OK. I'm not sure what the author meant by this, but it's obviously not just a check for possible null.

```
int LOG(const char* func, const char* file,
                 int lineno, severity level, const char* msg)
{
    const unsigned long u_func = (unsigned long)func;
    const unsigned long u_file = (unsigned long)file;
    const unsigned long u_msg   = (unsigned long)msg;

    if(u_func < 0x400 || u_file < 0x400 || u_msg  < 0x400 ||
       (unsigned)lineno > 10000 || (unsigned)level > LOG_DEBUG)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "log function called with bad args");
        return -1;
    }
    //...
}
```

Another possible use case for this would be storing boolean flags inside a pointer, instead in a separate member variable as an optimization. I think the C++11 small string optimization does this, but I might be wrong.

**EDIT:**

If it's implementation defined, as some of you have mentioned, can you detect it at compile time?

Comment: What's `u_func`, `u_file`, and `u_msg`? I only see `func`, `file`, and `msg` being defined.

Comment: No, you cannot. Even less with ASLR. There are cases where you know that some pointers cannot point to some types, but that's it.

Comment: I think this will largely depend on your platform ...

Comment: _De facto_ or by the standard? Afaik, on Linux, Windows and Mac, the result of `malloc` is always 16 byte aligned, so you could use the 4 LSB for additional storage. I think LLVM does exactly that. The standard does, of course, not guarantee anything like that.

Comment: Sorry there are some ugly casts I left out.

Comment: What is the target language? Please read descriptions like [tag:c] before applying the tags!

Comment: Pretty sure some of the bits on a pointer for x64 arch are guaranteed to be the same. I think Clang uses these bits to store data for its vector like data structure. Google "tagged pointer". I don't think it's portable, though.

Comment: `std::uintptr_t` seems better than `unsigned long`.

Comment: 0x400 = 1k which isn't too bad of a guess but ...

Comment: The language of the example is C

Comment: On embedded systems, the values depend on what is implemented by the hardware.  Some systems may allocate the entire address range, while others may only implement blocks or ranges of addresses.  The compiler can't know this information unless you provide it to the compiler.

Comment: IMHO, detecting an invalid pointer is easier done in hardware.  There are devices that can be programmed to check if an address is within a range or not, then generate an exception.  Many processors can throw an exception if there was an error fetching from an address, a.k.a. dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: There's nothing C++ specific to this question so it should have been tagged C only. Too late now though, answers are already posted.

Comment: Just to mention the obvious: Null pointers are probably not valid for use as arguments to the function above.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the standard restrict possible memory addresses (which I would interpret as possible values for a pointer)?

The C++ (nor C to my knowledge) standard does not restrict possible memory addresses.

> Can your code rely on some values to be never used and still be fully portable?

A program that unconditionally relies on such implementation defined (or unspecified by standard) detail would not be fully portable to all concrete and theoretical standard implementations.

However, using platform detection macros, it may be possible to make the program portable by relying on the detail conditionally only on systems where the detail is reliable.

---

P.S. Another thing that you cannot technically rely on: `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be able to represent all pointer values (`uintptr_t` is).

Answer (score 1):

The standard term is 'safely derived pointer'. It is implementation defined if you can use not safely derived pointers - for example, numeric constants - in your program.

You can check pointer safety model with `std::pointer_safety`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/pointer_safety

Comment: A bit related, but "safely derived pointer" isn't really about memory regions like the example attempts to check - it's more about a concern that a pointer which has exactly the same byte representation as a valid pointer might not be correct to use.

Comment: @aschepler the way I read it it applies. Standard outlines what safety derived pointers are (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety) and than says it's implementation defined if non-safely derived pointers are allowed. Which to me is a direct answer to initial question ("Does the standard restrict possible memory addresses ... which I would interpret as possible values for a pointer")

Comment: @SergeyA But does the standard specify a subset of memory address values that could potentially be safely derived?

Comment: @eerorika Not to my knowledge :)